# Symfony ManyToMany how to add 2 objects(same type, diffrent data) to a entity with avoiding duplcation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, many-to-many

So, I have a **User** < ManyToMany > **Conversation**. What I want to achieve is following.

I want to save 2 **User** objects(same type, different data) to a **Conversation**. I know doctrine doesn't duplicate it or it's something wrong with it. I know how it works and understand the workflow. I am just not capable of achieving what I really need.

My code for merging these objects looks like following

```
$first_user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->find($second_user);
$second_user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->find($second_user);

$conversation = new Conversation();

$conversation->addParticipator($first_user);
$conversation->addParticipator($second_user);
```

It currently adds 2 records to ***conversation*** and 4 records to ***conversation_user*** table. All I need is for it to add one record to ***conversation*** and 2 for ***conversation_user*** table.

I tried changing the relation to ManyToOne and somehow get it to work, but I failed. I also think it should be done by making use of ManyToMany relationship. Any help appreciated!

Comment: I think somehtink else is wrong in you code. May be you are calling this code twice. This code should work as you expect.

Comment: Yeah, i also thought there will be no problem but there I am. I am currently trying to insert it by using raw sql, but it's impossible as of now,